# Is "far further" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, comparatives, degree-of-comparison

"Between his support for packing the Supreme Court and legalizing abortion up until the point of birth, there's no question that Buttigieg was far further to the Left of former President Barack Obama." (Tiana Lowe, Washington Examiner op-ed, 3/1/20)

It seems to me that striking the word "further" would be a striking improvement, but that doesn't mean "far further" is simply wrong. Is it?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/farther-farthest-or-further-furthest.  Usually 'far' is followed by a comparative, like 'far better' (not sure of the correctness of 'far good'?). Further is in positive degree with its superlative 'furthermost' with no comparative form. But 'farther' goes like far, farther, farthermost. OP may review if this info helps.

Comment: The cited reference: 

"Farther and further are comparative adverbs or adjectives. They are the irregular comparative forms of far...There is no difference in meaning between them."

Comment: I think it's just wrong: further to the left of Obama **than whom**?